# why only one tooth of the gear is selected when control R is pressed

Tags: modeling

when I am selecting gear teeth for loop cut only one gear tooth is getting selected

Comment: Could you include any details? Screenshots, file, more details? For the file use [http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Is tooth of the gear made with circular Array? If yes, is it applied? If no what was used? etc

Comment: I have uploaded the blender file in  http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am understanding of the question, trying to loop cut all the teeth won't work because loop cuts only cut along the edge loop, which each tooth has a separate edge loop.

Because of this, you'll have to do them all individually and use a numerical value if you do a loop slide after the loop cut and make them all the same. If you are then going to scale these, you need to:

1. set the pivot to Individual origins
2. loop select all of the loops on each gear using SHIFT + ALT + Right Click and selecting each loop - one after another
3. once all loops are selected you can scale them.